# Is there any rtmp live streaming library in .net similar to node media server?

Tags: asp.net, .net, node.js, rtmp, live-streaming

Hi I'm looking for a rtmp live streaming library similar to node media server in .net
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-media-server

I have searched in Nugget package manager and git but not found any single solution which is similar to this.

1)I want a library in .net where I can be able to create rtmp streaming endpoint.

2)Be able to publish to it using OBS studio or similar encoder.

3)render it in html using any html video player.(This probably will not have to be covered in library)

also I'm not looking for iis media services. I'm looking for streaming library.

Comment: https://github.com/hinaria/rtmp-sharp

Comment: Hi @abney317 I have checked few options available on NugetPM. But cant find any documentation to go with them. If you have link to it kindly provide. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Hi @ashishshiwalkar Have you done with this?

Comment: hi @AnthonyWinzlet i'm currently using node media server but i'm still looking for any dot net alternative if available for my project.